# PyQGIS: iface.mapCanvas.selectionChanged sends two signals?

Tags: pyqgis

I need a signal on mouseclick, at best, when a new selection is done. I found the `selectionChanged` method, which, when connected, sends a signal however, as it seems, not when a new selection is done, but when you click somewhere (without you select a new feature), and further, the method sends two signals when clicked, and I only need one (as the function will be executed when it receives a signal).

Is there a way to suppress the second signal, or even another method to fetch the signal if a new feature selection is made?

```py
def FunctionThatReactsToTheSignal():
    print('selection changed')

mc=iface.mapCanvas()
mc.selectionChanged.connect(FunctionThatReactsToTheSignal)
```

Comment: IMHO, you have to connect the vector layers `selectionChanged` signals : https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ac32339abf885be1ed2262646e975dd87

Comment: Bear in mind that 'selection changed' does not necessarily mean 'feature selected'. Clicking somewhere on the canvas but not on a feature will cause any selected features in the active layer to be de-selected i.e. the selection has still changed so it makes sense that the signal is emitted.